# SVN Tree Conflict - just want to get the files?

Tags: svn

old SourceSafe user here, having to switch to SVN.  So, one of the projects in the trunk always says "Tree Conflict".  I haven't done any work in it (or at least nothing I need to keep).  I just want to "Get" exactly what's in the Repository for it.  Deleting the folder and updating doesn't seem to do the trick.  This should be simple; I don't care about what I have in the folder, I just want what's in the Repository.  How do I "Get" (in VSS terms) a project from SVN?

Answer (score 1):

[svn checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html)

I recommend using a client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) as well.

Tree conflicts usually occur when a file has been moved/deleted without using the SVN command to do so. However, there should never be a conflict when doing a fresh checkout into a new folder. Make sure the folder doesn't have any svn information attached to it by displaying "hidden" files and folders in your file explorer. You can try deleting the .svn folders if they exist or make a new checkout location in a directory that has no .svn files.

Comment: Sorry - yes, I'm using TortoiseSVN.  "Checkout" from the Repo Browser still gives me "Tree Conflict".

Comment: Have you tried checking out into a new directory? One with no .svn files? Also, try using the cleanup command. And if that still doesn't work. Right click, and select "Mark resolved." They recommit if needed.

Comment: Great, I added some more detail about what cause tree conflicts in my answer in case it happens again. Would also appreciate an accepted answer. =) Good luck.